# Bootstrap Modal keyboard & backdrop property issue for multiple modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've multiple modals but keyboard: false property not working in some cases:

**First event open Types model:**

```
$('.charts').click(function () {
    $('#ModalVTypes').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true });
});
```

**Second event open Matrics or Chart modal and hide Types model:**

```
$('.glist a').click(function () {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
    if (Type == 1) {
        $('#ModalMatrics').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true });
    } else {
        $('#ModalChart').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true });

    }
});
```

If i've use single modal its working fine.
Thanks

Comment: That's an id `#ModalVTypes`...how do you have multiple modals? Do you have multiple elements with the same ID? If so, there's your problem, use a class

Comment: No , Different modal on same page with different ID's

Comment: ok, then you need to show more of your code, one line doesn't really help - can you create a fiddle or bootply and show it not working?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney code has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been fond:

The issue with modal hide functionality.

```
$('.modal').modal('hide'); //Create issue because it'll reset all properties
```

Replaced this with following:

```
$('Model_ID').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give in HTML div modal element like below

```
 <div class="modal-open">
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalVTypes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Test modal</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```